# With the email address as the subscriber key, what happens if a user fills out a subscription form and they are already in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

We currently have "email address" as the subscriber key in Marketing Cloud.

Lets say we have Bob Smith already has a subscriber in the system:

Email: bobsmith@gmail.com - First Name: Bob - Last Name: Smith - Company: **Company A**

But then we subscribes again, through a different channel as a mistake or he doesn't realize he's already signed up, but some of his profile information has changed but not his email:

Email: bothsmith@gmail.com - First Name: Bob - Last Name: Smith - Company: **Company B**

How does Marketing Cloud handle this? Will the second entry bump out the first?

Comment: Can you mark accept this question if it answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: It depends.

If your instance uses Email Address as the subscriber key, it would update Bob's company from A to be B.

If your instance uses a different value  (eg Salesforce Id), the system would recognise them as two different subscribers.

Comment: Even further it depends on the method you are adding subscribers: Import, Web Collect, API, as each can be set to behave differently.